# How to apply a condition to a specific table in every request on Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, join, entity

I have a many-to-many structure mapped to entity framework. This is a sample of what it looks like:

```
User            UserTag             Tag
-------         --------            -------
IdUser(PK)      IdUserTag(PK)       IdTag(PK)
Name            IdUser(FK)          TagName
Desc            IdTag(FK)           Active
```

Now, I needed to exclude from any request of any method the viewing of **Tags** that were Active=false.

First, I tried doing it manually in every method, like:

```
public User GetById(int id)
{
    var item = UserRepository.GetById(id); //This is just a repository that calls the EF context

    //EF automatically maps it to the *UserTags* property
    foreach(var tag in item.UserTags)
    {
        if(tag.Tag.Active == false)
            item.UserTags.Remove(tag);
    }
}
```

But it throws the following exception:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

So, I wanted to know if there's a way to conditionaly filter every request made to a specific table, whether it is select or a join request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your GetById method:

```
var user.UserTags = dbContext.Entry(user)
                 .Collection(u => u.UserTags)
                 .Query()
                 .Where(ut => ut.Active == true)
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The supplied code fails because it is attempting to remove items from the data entities not the list.  If you want to pass the data entity around instead of the data model, you need to not use Remove.  Something like the below (untested should work).

```
tags = item.UserTags.Where((ut) => ut.Active).ToList();
```

This line will get you a list of data entities that are active.  However, you should really map all of this into a data model (see AutoMapper) and then you would not be removing items from the database.